# How to add MIB into Icinga?

Tags: snmp

How can I add MIB to Icinga? Are there any configuration or settings I need to make under Icinga?

I tested using iReasoning MIB Browser. I wanted to know how I can import MIB files to Icinga.

Comment: What do you want to do? What is your goal? Querying a resource via SNMP? Quering Icinga (not! iCinga) via SNMP?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import MIBs into Icinga in order to simply have Icinga plugins (via commands , via services) utilize OIDs.  You should be querying specific OIDs that you want and nothing more.

If you're concerned with handling SNMP traps, Icinga doesn't handle SNMP traps directly.

If you set up a service, you can use `snmptt` to pipe stuff into the Icinga command pipe with the whatever contents of the trap you wish (as qualified by `snmptt`), and have a single `passive service` (in icinga) handle all the traps or several `passive services` handle different traps.

A bulk of this configuration is done with `snmptt` which actually does need the MIBs to understand the OIDs that are contained in the traps.

Trust me, it'll take you a bit to get a hang of the whole thing, but you will get a hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

A full description of the Icinga configuration to receive SNMP Traps (including working with MIB files) here: [Icinga & SNMP Traps](https://blog.it-kb.ru/2017/08/23/deploy-and-configure-icinga-2-on-debian-8-part-13-2-snmp-trap-monitoring-of-network-devices-as-apc-eaton-ups-nmc-in-icinga-director/)